# Gasoline glow engine mechanics

Tags: engine-theory, gasoline, small-engine, glowplugs

I own a wide array of model engines. Typically those engines are either glow engines using nitro fuel, spark engines using gasoline or "diesel" engines using "kerosene". However I recently acquired a 6cc engine that runs using a glow plug (like a nitro engine), but it is fueled with gasoline.

I was curious, what are the mechanics that allow an engine to work on gasoline without a spark plug? Is it higher compression? Is it a special plug with a different catalyst that helps ignite the fuel/air mixture? Is it something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

The glow plug engines have a glow plug that gets heated from a power supply and once it is hot, the repeated combustion process is sufficient to keep it hot so that it can ignite the fresh incoming charge.

This can happen with gasoline engines that have suffered a build-up of carbon deposits and is often called "dieseling" or self-ignition, when the carbon stays ignited through the exhaust and intake part of the engine cycle.

Comment: That was my understanding of glow plug engines as well. But this engine I bought is specifically designed to run on gasoline fuel and it works perfectly fine. You preheat the glow plug, run it quite rich and it will start and run without any spark plug.

Comment: However if I take my run off the mill nitro engine and feed it with gasoline it wont start at all. So apparently the gasoline engine I have with the glow plug has something different compared to the nitro version of it. My question was, what is that thing that is different?

Comment: @YanickSalzmann That is what I said in my answer... But you may find the jets are different for nitro compared to gas...

Comment: But the gasoline engine does not have any carbon build up, it is pristine metal, both the piston/cylinder and the glow plug. Is the coil of the glow plug a different material from the nitro engine? In a way I might be able to rephrase my question to: "What do I need to do to turn my normal nitro glow engine into a gasoline glow engine?"

Comment: Why don't you check to see if there are different glow plugs for the different fuels? I would think to check that, as fuels have different combustion temperatures etc

Comment: It seems really hard to get specific information about it, everything I can find is "specifically designed for gasoline engines" usually. I wonder whats particular about them. They look exactly the same to the naked eye, but obviously the coil could be any material...

Comment: Are you certain this small gas engine uses a glow plug? A gasoline engine using a glow plug without a spark ignition system is new to me. I'm familiar with rc model engines before the revolution in lithium rechargeable batteries/electric motors replaced them. Model glow plugs use platinum reacting to the methanol/nitromethane model fuel mix allows the glow plug to continue glowing, igniting the model fuel. The gas engine glow plug may use a different type of element to ignite the air/fuel mixture. I can't find info of a gas engine using a glow plug. Can you post snapshots?

Comment: @FDryer I don’t own any small engines, 2.2 litres at the moment. If you wanted to send to the OP then you should. Also didn’t you write the same earlier so this is delete and repeat?

Comment: @SolarMike I deleted my initial comment to edit it for clarity. I don't have anything to send or post to help and asked the OP to post snapshots of this gasoline glow plug and maybe the entire engine for viewing since I can't find any info of gasoline glow plugs. There may be some confusion from the OPs descriptions.

Comment: I find these RC engines fascinating. A diesel engine that runs on methanol and nitromethane. You don't find this in many applications and nitro methane is such a harsh fuel, detonating like an explosive. Nitromethane can also be used as a mono-propellant.